# How to select without column names in python with pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I want to select a row in mysql, I do like this:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
                        host='10.0.0.11', 
                        port=3306,
                        user='root', 
                        password='159753arazr', 
                        db='bili_1810', 
                        charset='utf8', 
                        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = conn.cursor()
table_name = ['24569', '25510']
for x in table_name:
    sql = "SELECT `播放`, `关注`, `弹幕`, `硬币` FROM `"+x+"` LIMIT %s, 1"
    cursor.execute(sql, (9))
    conn.commit()
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
conn.close()
```

The result is:

```
[{'播放': '25824', '关注': '3071', '弹幕': '141', '硬币': '107'}]
[{'播放': '0', '关注': '1244460', '弹幕': '0', '硬币': '0'}]
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
[{'25824', '3071', '141', '107'}]
[{'0', '1244460', '0', '0'}]
```

Just without the column names, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know your API well, but my feeling is that must be a way to iterate your JSON content and just extract values (but not keys).  So, my answer is don't change anything; learn how to manipulate JSON in your Python code.

Comment: Try using `pymysql.cursors.Cursor` as `cursorclass`.

Comment: Dude you should really anonymize your input before you post it here. There are still people like myself on stackoverflow who understand Chinese and know what is bilibili.

Answer (score 2):

As your result shown, you got a list which covers the items you queried in a dict struct.If you want to get your wanted result like that, you can try this:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
result_values = [iter_item for iter_item in map(lambda item: [item[key]
                                          for key in item.keys()], result)]
```

In this way, you can get like `[[]]` instead of `[{}]`, but this guarantee the value order. If you just want set, you can use this:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
result_values = [iter_item for iter_item in map(lambda item: set([item[key]
                                          for key in item.keys()]), result)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
By default it gives in the required format without keys.